# Using AND and OR in Elasticsearch Python API queries

Tags: elasticsearch-dsl

Right now I have

```
s = Search(using = client, index = set_index).query('match', 
StartDate = ((seven) or (six) or (three)))
```

I want to return hits that have a start date that is equal to either the variable seven, the variable six, or the variable three.

Comment: You should use the bool query with should clauses (for OR) or must clauses (for AND)

Comment: please take a look here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/lost-in-translation-boolean-operations-and-filters-in-the-bool-query

Answer (score 0):

Please see the reply on the github issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/955#issuecomment-405764243